# Show that the rank of I-P is n-p.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:

Show that the rank of $\mathbf{I}_{n}-\mathbf{P}$ is $n-p$ (where $\mathbf{P}$ is a matrix that projects on to the subspace generated by the columns of $\mathbf{X}$).

--I am thinking that the trace of $\mathbf{I}_{n}-\mathbf{P}$ equals $n-p$, so then the rank equals $n-p$ as well, since $\mathbf{I}_{n}-\mathbf{P}$ is symmetric and idempotent. I am just not sure if there are important steps that I am missing here. Why does trace$(\mathbf{P})=p$?

Answer (score 0):

Trace does not give you enough information about the rank. For example, $\operatorname{diag}(2,0)$ has trace $2$, but rank only $1$. You'd have to prove that in the case of projectors this cannot happen, i.e., that the trace really does give you enough information on the rank.

Hint: Start with the defining property of a projector, $P^2 = P$, and use the Jordan decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If $\mathbf{P}$ is a projection matrix, then isn't it true that it is both symmetric and idempotent? if so, then rank$(P)=$rank$(X)$ where rank$(X)=p$ (I forgot to include this). Furthermore, if $\mathbf{P}$ is idempotent, then rank$(P)=$trace$(P)$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is self-adjoint iff the projection is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $p = \dim {\cal R} P$.

Let $v_1,...,v_p$ be a basis for ${\cal R} P$. Since $P$ is a projection, we have $Pv_k = v_k$, for $k =1,...,p$. We note in passing that $(I-P) v_k = 0$.

Extend the basis to the whole space with vectors $w_{p+1},...,w_n$. That is, $v_1,...,v_p, w_{p+1},...,w_n$ forms a basis for the whole space.

I claim $(I-P)w_k$, for $k=p+1,...,n$ are linearly independent and ${\cal R} (I-P) = \operatorname{sp} \{ (I-P)w_k \}_{k \ge p+1}$.

Suppose $\sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k (I-P)w_k = 0$, then $\sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k w_k = \sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k P w_k = P (\sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k w_k) $. However, since $v_1,...,v_p$ is a basis for ${\cal R} P$, we have $P (\sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k w_k) = \sum_{i=1}^p \gamma_i v_i$, and so we have
$ \sum_{k=p+1}^n \beta_k w_k + \sum_{i=1}^p (-\gamma_i) v_i = 0$. Hence we have 
$\beta_k = 0$, and so the $(I-P)w_k$ are linearly independent.

Now let $x=\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i v_i+ \sum_{j=p+1}^n \beta_j w_j$, then $(I-P) x = \sum_{j=p+1}^n \beta_j (I-P)w_j$, which shows that 
${\cal R} (I-P) = \operatorname{sp} \{ (I-P)w_k \}_{k \ge p+1}$. Hence $\dim {\cal R} (I-P) = n-p$.

**Aside**: The above analysis shows that in fact, $v_1,...,v_p, (I-P)w_{p+1},...,(I-P)w_n$ is a basis. To see this, suppose
$\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i v_i+ \sum_{j=p+1}^n \beta_j (I-P)w_j = 0$.
Multiplying by $P$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i v_i = 0$, and so we have $\alpha_i = 0$. Then the above shows that $\beta_j = 0$ also, hence the vectors are linearly independent. Since there are $n$ of them, they form a basis. Or, since $x = Px + (I-P)x$, and $Px \in {\cal R}p$ and $(I-P)x \in {\cal R}(I-P)$, we have the desired result.

**Note 1**: A projection does not have to be symmetric, for example $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is easily seen to be a projection onto $\operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}$, but is clearly not symmetric.

**Note 2**: To see why the trace is $p$, consider the operator $P$ in the basis 
$v_1,...,v_p, (I-P)w_{p+1},...,(I-P)w_n$ described above. We have $P(\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i v_i+ \sum_{j=p+1}^n \beta_j (I-P)w_j) = \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i v_i$. Hence in this basis, $P$ is diagonal with $p$ ones and $n-p$ zeros, and so $\operatorname{tr} P = p$.